# Analytics for nodejs + extjs webkit application

Tags: node.js, webkit, google-analytics, analytics, usage-statistics

I am developing nodejs webkit application. I am using extjs for UI. Application will be installed by anyone, we would like to track application usage using some analytics system, may be google analytics or any opensource tracker.I know google analytics does not support usage tracking for desktop apps. Since app is developed on nodejs webkit it will run on tablets and smart phone too. 
Please guide on possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

We created pages on server and requested same from app. We used piwik to track pages. 
It worked.